# incompatible types cannot be converted to

Tags: java

Estou começando a estudar java e após observar a criação de alguns objetos resolvi tentar criar os meus próprios. já no primeiro encontrei esse erro que nao sei resolver "incompatible types cannot be converted to", esse fica na linha, e quando tento compilar aparece assim.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: desodorante.Desoclasse cannot be converted to desodorante.Desodorante
>       at desodorante.Desodorante.main(Desodorante.java:4)"

Não tem nenhuma outra linha com erro, e meu objeto tá bem parecido com o dos exemplos. alguém pode me ajudar?

```
package desodorante;

public class Desodorante {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Desodorante c1 = new Desoclasse(); //essa é a linha com erro

package desodorante; //aqui a classe
public class Desoclasse {
    String cor;
    String perfume;
    int carga;
    int peso;
    boolean levantado;
```

Comment: Você pecebe que ta tentando transformar um objeto `Desodorante ` em um do tipo `Desoclasse` sendo que essas classe não tem nada a ver uma com a outra?

Comment: Em resumo: `Desodorante != Desoclasse`

Answer (score 2):

O problema é a incompatibilidade de Tipos, como a própria Exception está dizendo:

> incompatible types: desodorante.Desoclasse cannot be converted to desodorante.Desodorante

Vamos analisar o porque isto ocorre:

```
Desodorante c1 = new Desoclasse();
```

1. A variável `c1` foi declarada como sendo do Tipo `Desodorante`,
2. Você criou um Objeto do Tipo `Desoclasse` ao fazer `new Desoclasse()`,
3. Por fim, você tentou atribuir à variável `c1` (que é do Tipo `Desodorante`) o Objeto criado que é do Tipo `Desoclasse`!

> Por isto ocorreu o erro: `Desoclasse` não *é-um* `Desodorante`.

Para resolver isto, podemos fazer `Desoclasse` passar a *ser-um* `Desodorante`, assim:

```
public class Desoclasse extends Desodorante {...}
```

Outra forma de resolver, é fazer a variável `c1` ser capaz de receber um Objeto `Desoclasse`, o que podemos fazer assim:

```
Desoclasse c1 = new Desoclasse();
```

Como todos os Objetos *são-um* `Object` (`java.lang.Object`), também podemos fazer assim:

```
Object c1 = new Desoclasse();
```

---

Os conceitos apresentados aqui tem haver com **Polimorfismo** e **Herança**, ao estudá-los você irá compreender melhor isto.

Comment: Muito obrigado kra!
pela ajuda e pela gentileza.
continuarei meus estudos!